# How to insert same value primary key and foreign?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two table and t1 is the primary key of the a1 table and t1 is the foreign key of the a2 that reference the table(t1)

A1 Create Table

```
    CREATE TABLE `a1` (
            `t1` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            `t2` CHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
            PRIMARY KEY (`t1`)
    )
    COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    AUTO_INCREMENT=0
;
```

A2 Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE `a2` (
        `t1` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        `t2` CHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
        INDEX `FK__a1` (`t1`),
        CONSTRAINT `FK__a1` FOREIGN KEY (`t1`) REFERENCES `a1` (`t1`) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
;
```

and I try to insert Query that is as below

INSERT into a1(t2) values ('test1');
INSERT into a2(t2) values ('test2');

Look at the execution result

```
A1 Table
t1  │ t2
─────────
1   │ test1

A2 Table
t1  │ t2
─────────
null│ test1
```

why t1 of the a2 tlable value is null?
I want to insert auto_increment the value of t1(a1 table) to insert t1(a2 table)

please let me know best way! thanks your answer!

Comment: It's `null` because you **didn't provide** a value for it. Look at your insert: `INSERT into a2(t2) values ('test2');` - where's the value for `t1` column? Did you think if you add foreign keys that these things happen automatically?

Comment: @Mjh yes.. i think that automatically fiil out..

Comment: @HighEndGuy, are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?!?

Comment: No, it doesn't automatically fill out. That's not what foreign keys do. How could the insert into `a2` *know* that it should link against latest entry in `a1`? The computer would have to **guess** and computers don't do that :)

Comment: @jarlh - the tables in the question specify `auto_increment` and `ENGINE=InnoDB` - both being **MySQL**-specific...

Comment: @Mjh, yes, and in a below comment OP asks "Is it possible to be used in the MsSql?", which made me wonder...

Comment: @jarlh noted, I didn't see it, sorry.

Comment: @Mjh, no problem at all. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is `null` value in `t1 of A2` table because you have mentioned `NULL DEFAULT NULL` in table design for t1 column in A2 table.

You have to pass the value of t1 from A1 column when you are inserting into A2 table.

You can use some query like this. I am not sure.

INSERT into a2(t1,t2) values (select t1 ,'test2' from A1 where t2='test2');

Comment: I have mentioned that I am not sure. Please correct it if you can. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use[`LAST_INSERT_ID()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id):

```
INSERT into a1(t2) values ('test1'); 

INSERT into a2(t1,t2) values ( LAST_INSERT_ID(),'test2');
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/033ea/1/0)**</kbd>

Comment: @lad205 Is it possible to be used in the MsSql?

Comment: @HighEndGuy Check [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/398766) and `SCOPE_IDENTITY`